# Can't create matrix function of symbolic functions and assign values to elements

Tags: functions, matrix, symbolic, numerical-value, assignment

So I have a problem regarding the symbolic matrix value assignment.

Say I create a matrix function as:

```
P[t_]:= {{P1[t]}, {P2[t]}, {P3[t]}};
```

Then I want to assign value:

`P[t][[1,1]]=1`. But I get an error, something like "P[t] in the part assignment is not a symbol."

Am I doing something wrong?

Just to clarify, I would like a solution with not individual value assignment like `P[t][[1,1]]./{...}`, because I may have a matrix with a lot of elements so, ideally, I would like to automate the procedure for hundreds of elements.
Also, I am not including the explicit definition of my matrix function because it is messy, but if you think it can help I can provide it.

Thanks!

Last edit: Here's my code below

`Pmat[t_] := {{"1,1", P11[t]}, {"0,2", P02[t]}, {"1,3",P13[t]}, {"2,4", P24[t]}}; Pmat[0][[1,2]]=3`

Comment: What are the dimensions of `P..[t]` `/;` assuming that these are lists or a matrices? And please  switch to lowercase `p` as uppercase symbols are considered reserved.

Comment: `Set` (i.e `=`) has attribute `HoldFirst`, so *LHS* is not evaluated in `P[t][[1,1]]=1`. On the other hand,  `Evaluate[P[t][[1,1]]]=1` "works" but I'm not sure if that is the behaviour you are after, because I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Part assignment only works with variable assignments like `var = {...}`. It does not work with DownValues (i.e., functions). The closest you can come is with something like `DownValues[P] = ReplacePart[ DownValues[P], {1, 2, 1, 1} -> 1 ]`. It's not exactly standard procedure and I don't recommend this type of programming, but it will work. But why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: @rhermans can u check my edited post?

Comment: @NikolaosPetropoulos I don't understand what you want to do.  Can you please [edit] your question and provide actual *Mathematica* code in a formatted form (neither images nor $\LaTeX$ ) that is a minimal working example of the starting point and the desired output?

Comment: @rhermans I have created a matrix as in the picture I uploaded in the edited post. I have created a matrix function Pmat[t] that has symbolic functions of t as second column. I want for a specific t=0 to assign to one of those entries the value 3.

Comment: Nikolaos, your post does not include the code to make the matrix you include a picture of; the picture alone is useless here without the code to reproduce it.

Comment: ok you can check the code above (I didn't want to include it as it's super messy)

Comment: If it's safe to evaluate `P[t]`, then something line `P[t_] = Block[{t}, ReplacePart[P[t], {1, 1} -> 3]]` or `P[0] = ReplacePart[P[0], {1, 1} -> 3]`? Beware that integers like `0` and reals like `0.` are not the same object, and `P[0.]` will use the value for `P[t_]` and not for `P[0]`.

Comment: I already mentioned this, but as a more in-depth reminder, here we considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a [well-formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) **instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Comment: @rhermans is it better in my last edit?